# Where is openfl project directory?

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

in the tutorial they said

> Open the "Source/Main.hx" file in the editor of your choice. It should look something like this:

but i don't where is that file?

http://www.openfl.org/learn/tutorials/your-first-project/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, if you run "openfl create project HelloWorld" and cmd points to

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\
```

the project directory will be

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\HelloWorld\Source\Main.hx
```

It depends what directory is in cmd when you run that command.

Comment: AFAIK the project is created in the current dir, so that is only true if you run the command in your home directory

Comment: where if on macintosh? cause i use macintosh, i am search using finder  with keyword "HelloWorld"but doesn’t exist

Comment: owh yes thanks, i couldn't find cause my current path/directory is in on hidden path. after i change path and it's work successfully/